# How to get a list of all windows in Xorg?

Tags: linux, xorg

I would like to get a list of all windows in Xorg, with their window ids and names. How can I do it? I know about xwininfo, but I have to click on a particular window to get its id.

PS: I am using window managers with multiple workspaces and I want the list of all windows, from all workspaces, not just the current one.

PPS: I've also had a look at xwininfo -tree -root, but its output isn't really a list, and judging by window names, it seems to have some redundant data (windows with same name listed multiple times), unless I'm misunderstanding the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `window manager` is  *EWMH- and NetWM-compatible* you can use [`wmctrl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl):

```
$ wmctrl  -l
0x01a0000e  0 N/A Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
0x0120000d  0 comp uxterm
0x01000010  0 comp linux - How to get a list of all windows in Xorg? - Super User - firefox
0x00a00013  0 comp emacs@comp.lan
```